# vectorized calculation of mean and sem of unique float values in each row of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, rows, mean

I want to calculate mean (i.e. numpy.mean) and sem (i.e. scipy.stats.sem) of unique float values in each row of a pandas DataFrame in a **vectorized** way.

Example input:

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1':[1.,2.,3.,4.],
                       'c2':[1.,2.,3.,3.],
                       'c3':[1.,2.,2.,2.],
                       'c4':[1.,1.,1.,1.]})
t.index.name = 'i'
# unique values: [1] [1,2] [1,2,3] [1,2,3,4]
```

Expected result:

```
   mean       sem
i                
0   1.0       NaN
1   1.5  0.500000
2   2.0  0.577350
3   2.5  0.645497
```

***Please, do not submit not vectorized solutions*** like this:

```py
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as ss
def fun(x):
    r = x.transpose()[x.index[0]].value_counts(sort=False).rename('count')
    r.index.name = 'value'
    y = r.index.values
    return pd.DataFrame({'mean':np.mean(y), 'sem':ss.sem(y)}, index=[0])

t2 = t.groupby(t.index.names).apply(fun)
t2.index = t2.index.droplevel(1)
```

The real DataFrame has >1e12 rows, so not efficient solutions won't do.

Ideally, it would be great to have a condition of uniqueness (i.e. abs difference or deviation of ratio from one) of float values, but any efficient solution would be awesome to have.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I do not believe a vectorized solution is possible - mostly because pandas has no vectorized function for uniqueness detection.

Comment: @DYZ: Pandas does have such functions. For example, `pandas.Series.value_counts`, `pandas.Series.unique`, `pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique`, `pandas.unique` etc. The question is if there is a way to combine such functions efficiently. I believe the solution would transpose the input DataFrame, such that the rows would become columns and then apply one of the uniqueness functions on Series columns. Note, that the real DataFrame has MultiIndex, and so some care is needed when doing it.

Comment: All functions that you mentioned are applicable only to Series, not to a dataFrame. Which means that they have to be applied to one row at a time. So, they are not vectorized.

Comment: @DYZ: If that is the case, I would have to write C++ code to do it. The huge bummer is that there is no C++ analogue of pandas, and so I would have to figure out a way to convert a pandas DataFrame into a list of C++ arrays and then convert them back into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: In the real problem, do you have a bound on the number of columns?  1e12 rows is a lot, so even pretty efficient approaches will be awfully slow after multiplying by that N.

Comment: @DYZ: In the real problem, I have a finite number of columns which is not large. But different columns might contain duplicated information, and so only unique values have to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `pandas` have `sem` , you do not need to call `scipy`

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(list(map(set,t.values)))
newdf.T.agg(['mean','sem']).T
Out[436]: 
   mean       sem
0   1.0       NaN
1   1.5  0.500000
2   2.0  0.577350
3   2.5  0.645497
```

Comment: While it works correctly, this solution is very slow. Applying it on 1000 rows takes 2.8 seconds, which translates into 88 years for 1e12 rows.

Comment: @S.V slow than yours ?

Comment: @S.V sem is time cost function , you may look at cpython , or find the trend in your original data and optimized.

Comment: My solution is only 3 times slower than yours. In your solution: `map` takes 2e-4 sec, `+list` takes 7e-3 sec, `+DataFrame` takes 1e-2 sec, `+.T` takes 1e-2 sec, `+agg` takes 2.8 sec, `+.T` takes 2.8 sec. So, the slowest part is the `agg` call. If instead of `agg(['mean','sem'])` I call `.mean()` and `.sem()` separately, the solution takes 3e-2 seconds. So that is one way to make it 100 times faster. So `mean` and `sem` are fast, but this way `agg['mean','sem'])` of calling them that is slow.

Comment: @S.V then let us do single call then concat them together

Comment: Yes, here is the fast version: `t2 = pd.DataFrame(list(map(set,t.values))).T; pd.DataFrame({'mean':t2.mean().T, 'sem':t2.sem().T})`. The time reduces from 2.8 sec to 1e-2 sec.

Comment: @S.V great , I did not test the timing on my side , thank for share the information.

Comment: Thank you for providing the core ideas!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an *almost* vectorized solution, the only non-vectorized operation is creating your mask, which is *mostly* vectorized, but you  have to create one per column.

```
m = np.column_stack([t[col].duplicated() for col in t])
out = t.mask(m)
pd.DataFrame({'mean': np.mean(out), 'sem':ss.sem(out, nan_policy='omit').data})
```

```
    mean       sem
c1   2.5  0.645497
c2   2.0  0.577350
c3   1.5  0.500000
c4   1.0  0.000000
```

I don't have enough memory to test this on your size DataFrame, but here is a sample on 1-million row DataFrame:

```
t = pd.concat([t]*250000)

In [649]: %%timeit
     ...: m = np.column_stack([t[col].duplicated() for col in t])
     ...: out = t.mask(m)
     ...: pd.DataFrame({'mean': np.mean(out), 'sem':ss.sem(out, nan_policy='omit').data})
     ...:
326 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Yep, timing it now!

Comment: It seems to me that this solution searches for unique values in columns, and not in rows. Try to apply it to my example input, but with an extra row [5.,4.,3.,1.] added to it. Your solution will completely change the results for the 1st 4 rows and the resulting DataFrame will have dimensions 4x2. While the expected result is that the 1st 4 rows of the result would stay the same and the result should have shape 5x2.

Comment: @S.V if it's per row, then this solution is still really slow because of how long it takes to create the initial mask.